# Como impedir que seja criada uma JSESSIONID ao acessar uma página JSP?

Tags: session, jsp

Criei uma página JSP simples, que não faz nada além de chamar um servlet para validar um login. Eis o código da página `index.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="validalogin" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="user"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="senha" name="pass"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando executo esse código, automaticamente é gerada uma JSESSIONID, como na imagem a seguir. O problema é que isso acontece antes mesmo de chamar o servlet, ou seja, o JSP está criando uma sessão:
[image: imagem]

O formulário será enviado para o servlet (onde será criada/validada a sessão), mas como a página está criando uma automaticamente, quando a requisição chega no servlet ele dá a sessão como válida por já ter sido criada anteriormente.

Eu limpei os *cookies* do navegador e atualizei a página (<kbd>F5</kbd>), o resultado foi o mesmo: Foi gerada uma nova JSESSIONID.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e encontrei algo relacionado ao assunto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/598923/4056678) no StackOverflow, onde o autor cita que:

> Every call to JSP page implicitly creates new session if there is no
>   session yet. This can be turned off by `session='false'` page directive,
>   in which case session variable is not available on JSP page at all.

Depois disso, eu atualizei a diretiva da minha página para a seguinte:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false" %>
```

E quando limpei os *cookies* e atualizei a página, novamente foi gerada uma JSESSIONID.

---

Não sei se é algo relacionado ao servidor, mas estou usando o Apache Tomcat. Até cheguei a procurar no arquivo de configuração `server.xml` por algo relacionado com criação automática de sessão e não encontrei nada.

Como faço para modificar esse comportamento? Juntei todos os detalhes que achei relevante para pergunta, se faltou algum podem cobrar nos comentários.

Comment: Talvez esse link possa te ajudar...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml

Comment: @GuilhermeIazzetta Isso vai "matar" qualquer sessão. Eu só não gostaria que fosse iniciada uma sessão ao acessar uma página JSP. Essa sessão será criada depois que o usuário foi validado, quem criará será o servlet (e não a página, como está sendo feito). Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas e apanhar muito tentando resolver, consegui. E a solução foi usar o `session="false"` que citei na pergunta e que já havia tentado anteriormente sem sucesso.

Quando declarei a diretiva na forma a seguir, a sessão era criada (mesmo definida como `false`):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
```

Porém, quando defini esse atributo em uma diretiva separada a sessão deixou de ser criada, exatamente como eu precisava que ocorresse. Não entendi o motivo pois não li/encontrei nada dizendo que a ordem da declaração pode interferir em algo, mas o problema foi resolvido com:

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Também funcionou com:

```
<%@page session="false" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```